# Check if string contains dash and add double quotes to the word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to detect if string contains dash and add double quotes at the beginning of word and at the end of the word. If there is only a dash we should skip it. Also, the word with dash should be replaced if contains only numbers.

Input: test-dash - good example 123-123
Output: test-dash - good example "123-123"

So far I have REGEX like \S*[0-9]+\S* but it matches 7 places.
Language: C#

Update: current version: https://regex101.com/r/RKgDXE/1

Comment: Do you want to wrap with quotes strings like  `-123` and `123-` or `1-2-3-4`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Regex.Replace` method with pattern: `(\d+-\d+)`

Pattern explanation:

`(...)` - capturing group

`\d+` - match one ore more digits

`-` - match dash literally

Code sample:

```
var parsedString = Regex.Replace("test-dash - good example 123-123", @"(\d+-\d+)", "\"$1\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
string pattern = @"\d+[-]\d+$";
string input = "test-dash - good example 123-123";
string output = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value;
Console.WriteLine(input.Replace(output, string.Format("\"{0}\"", output)));

// output
// test-dash - good example "123-123"
```